# Changing text with slideToggle() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I want to change the text inside a element when the visibility of the table is toggled. I am able to toggle them but not able to change the text inside the element.

```
<table class="table funds-table">
<thead class="table-head">
<tr>
  <th id="equity-text">EQUITY</th>
  <th id="eq-show-less">SHOW LESS</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id = "equity-body">
 <tr>

  <td class = "fund-name">

    <div class = "col-xs-1 padding-lr-zero checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" id = "checkbox1">
      <label for="checkbox1"><span class="checkbox"><img src="icons/check_dis.png"></span></label></div>

    <div class = "col-xs-11 fund-name-div"><span class = "span-fund-name">HDFC DYNAMIC FUND HDFC DYNAMIC FUND HDFC DYNAMIC</span><p class = "currently-inv"> Currently invested <span class = "curr-span-amt">Rs. 50,000</span></p></div>

  </td>

  <td class = "fund-amount"><p class = "fund-amount-inner">Rs. 50,00,000</p></td>
</tr>

<tr>

  <td class = "fund-name">

    <div class = "col-xs-1 padding-lr-zero checkbox-div"><input type="checkbox" id = "checkbox2">
      <label for="checkbox2"><span class="checkbox"><img src="icons/check_dis.png"></span></label></div>

    <div class = "col-xs-11 fund-name-div"><span class = "span-fund-name">HDFC DYNAMIC FUND HDFC DYNAMIC FUND HDFC DYNAMIC</span></div>

  </td>

  <td class = "fund-amount"><p class = "fund-amount-inner">Rs. 50,00,000</p></td>
</tr>
```

It alerts when the `tbody` is `visible` but not when it is `hidden`.

```
  $('#eq-show-less').on('click',function(){

    $('#equity-body').slideToggle('slow');

  });


  $(function(){
    if ($('#equity-body').is(':visible')) {
      $('#eq-show-less').text("SHOW LESS");
      alert('visible');
    }

    if($('#equity-body').is(':hidden')){
      $('#eq-show-less').text("SHOW MORE");
      alert('not visible');
    }
  });
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knmfmftx/)

i want to change the text to **show less** when the `tbody` is visible and **show more** when `tbody` is hidden

Comment: Most of jquery methods have callback, this is the place where you can do some more action after function is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you only check the `:visible` state of the element when the page loads.

To fix this you need to check it when the `fadeToggle()` animation completes. To do that you can use the callback parameter, like this:

```
$('#eq-show-less').on('click', function() {
    $('#equity-body').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $('#eq-show-less').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'SHOW LESS' : 'SHOW MORE');
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/knmfmftx/2/)